# Adding Comments To Name in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I recently observed something that confused me a little bit:

I gave a range on my sheet a specific name using vba:

```
wks.Names.Add name:="databases", RefersTo:="=" & "$F$7:$F$" & j
```

That works totally fine for me and the name can be seen in the name manager with the correct reference.

In the next line of code I want to add a comment to this name using

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names("databases").Comment = "created automatically by <sub> on " & Now()
```

When adding this comment to the name, the reference for the name is changed and the name doesn't work anymore. I am really interested in why that occurs.

Comment: When you attempt to use it, and it doesn't work, are you on the sheet referred to in the `wks` object?

Comment: I just tried to recreate it from what you have shown and it worked fine, this implies something else is the issue in what you have not shown. Try the idea from Shai Rado

Comment: " the reference for the name is changed and the name doesn't work anymore" what does it change to? and does it work i.e. if you use the name its changed to does it work or is it actually corrupted?

Comment: I am only using one workbook and all worksheets are in that workbook.

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add name:="databases", RefersTo:="=" & "$F$7:$F$" & j - 1
  
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("databases").Comment = created automatically by <sub> on " & Now()

changes the name to 
    =Start!'R7C6':R20C6'

Comment: Are you examining the properties of the Name in Excel?  or in VBA?  Prepending the Sheet Name is normal behavior; in Excel, you may see what you show if your worksheet is set to use R1C1 notation instead of A1 notation (Check File ► Options ► Formulas ► Working with formulas

Comment: my settings are for A1 notation. I examine the properties in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce the problem, in Excel 2016. It does not happen in Excel 2010 nor 2013. It is a bug in the .Comment implementation.

A workaround:

```
sRefersTo= "Sheet1!$a$3"
Set MyName = .Names.Add(sName, sRefersTo)
With MyName
    .Comment = "created automatically by <sub> on " & Now() 
         ' .RefersTo has been changed to Sheet1!'R3C1' (note the extra '')
    .RefersTo= sRefersTo ' This fixes by re-setting
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Ray, works like a charm (Though, I had to change ".Names" into "Names").

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to re create the issue but I would recommend being more explicit in your declarations to avoid ambiguity.

For example your `wks` may refer to sheet called `DB_Data`, and the named range works fine, but `ActiveWorkbook` refers to the workbook that is active at the time, and it may not be the workbook that `wks` is in.

By being explicit you know exactly what you are dealing with i.e.

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim WkBk    As Excel.Workbook
Dim WkSht   As Excel.Worksheet
Dim Nm      As Excel.Name

Set WkBk = Application.Workbooks("Book1")
    Set WkSht = WkBk.Worksheets("DB_List")
        Set Nm = WkSht.Names.Add(Name:="databases", RefersTo:="=" & WkSht.Name & "!$F$7:$F$20")
            Nm.Comment = "Created automatically by <sub> on " & Now()
        Set Nm = nothng
    Set WkSht = Nothing
Set WkBk = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried that one in my code and setting the comment changes the name reference to:
`=Start!'R7C6':R20C6'`

Comment: You are probably aware of R1C1 and A1 notation, `Start!` defines the worksheet name (Start) and is common to both notation, `R7C6:20C6` is the R1C1 notation, `F7:F20` is the A1 notation but they both relate to the same range. I have made a small change to my example in the `RefersTo` setting, it now specifies the sheet name to be more explicit (my bad!). try that.

Comment: Tried that and it produces the same problem. When commenting out the line that produces the comment, it works perfectly (as did my code). When setting the comment the reference of the name changes to a `R7C6:20C6`.

Comment: ...bit of a hack, could you not just set the name a second time?

Comment: I think you are really going to add more code sample for us to get an idea of how to do this. However, I would also explore the comment from @YowE3K. The only way we can see it happening is if you have to named ranges of databases, which is possible if one it worksheet-scope and one is workbook-scope.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting the comment causes a vba error, but the comment is inserted correctly.
So: insert "On Error Resume Next" before the comment insertion code line and it works.
Hi.
Rahancrau

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the code below:

```
Sub DefandModNames()
'
Dim MyName As Name
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
'j = 10 '<-- for my tests only

With ActiveWorkbook
    Set MyName = .Names.Add(Name:="databases", RefersTo:="=" & wks.Name & "!$F$7:$F$" & j)
    With MyName
        .Comment = "created automatically by <sub> on " & Now()
    End With
End With    

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't that going to create a workbook-scope name, rather than a worksheet-scoped one?

Comment: @YowE3K yes, I think this is what the PO is after for (reading his last line where he gets his error). I think he's creating it in `wks` just because he wants the Named Range to get the range form this sheet.

Comment: The only way I can replicate the behaviour described by the OP is if more than one sheet has been set up with a `databases` range (which then means the name to which the comment is added may not be the one they are expecting to change), and then they try to use the name on another sheet on which there is no name defined.  I'm not sure whether the use of worksheet-scoped names is deliberate or a mistake on the OP's part.